# Using Html.ActionLink() with ASP.NET MVC & Spark - Syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

All, 
Doing some experimenting with Spark and MVC within NerdDinner.  The normal/aspx view works well, and I haven't touched any of the controller code so I'm pretty sure it's not that.

```
<viewdata model="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[[NerdDinner.Models.Dinner]]"/>
<set Title="'Upcoming Dinners'"/>
<content:main>

<li each="p in Model">
!{Html.ActionLink(p.Title, 'Details', 'Dinners')}
</li>

</content:main>
```

Given the code above, the ActionLink gets rendered as http://serverName/Controller/Action/
Which is good.  I start hitting a wall when I try to provide the ID to my action method.  As far as I can tell from the Spark sample docs, I should be able to do something like this:

```
!{Html.ActionLink(p.Title, 'Details', 'Dinners', new {id = p.DinnerID} )}
```

However, that throws an exception: 
" unexpected token '{' "

I'm hoping it's something silly I'm missing...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there should be another parameter to Html.ActionLink for HTML attributes on the action link.  Try:

```
!{Html.ActionLink(p.Title, 'Details', 'Dinners', new {id = p.DinnerID}, null )}
```